# Is there any equivalent of java's ExceptionListener in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

Is there any equivalent of java's "ExceptionListener" interface in C#. Or any such interface or method in C# gives an output similar to it?

Comment: My guess as with many other one-method Java interfaces, simple delegate would be equivalent of [ExceptionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/ExceptionListener.html) interface.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, If you don't mind can u plz provide some examples?!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Perhaps elaborate more. All `ExceptionListener` does it get invoked on a given exception. What exactly are you looking to do in C#?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I need to find such an exception which are UN-handled and internal exception. Means as I understood, by implementing "ExceptionListener" interface, it will invoke "exceptionThrown" automatically whenever UN-handled exception are found. According to "[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/ExceptionListener.html)". I am new to C# and all so, let me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AllizzWelll You can look at [`AppDomain.UnhandeledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: Thank you all, It may help.